# how to convert dataframe to list in R by id?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I've been struggling whole evening to figure out how to do this in R.

Basically I have a dataset like the following:

```
id<-c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3)
label<-c('a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e')
mydata<-as.data.frame(cbind(id, label))
mydata$id<-as.integer(as.character(mydata$id))
mydata$label<-as.character(mydata$label)
mydata
  id label
1  1     a
2  1     b
3  1     c
4  2     b
5  2     d
6  3     a
7  3     c
8  3     d
9  3     e
```

I want to transform mydata into mylist to look like the following:

```
mylist<-list()
mylist[[1]]<-c('a', 'b', 'c')
mylist[[2]]<-c( 'b', 'd')
mylist[[3]]<-c( 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e')
mylist
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "d"

[[3]]
[1] "a" "c" "d" "e"
```

So, how do I go form mydata to mylist?

NOTE: my actual dataframe has ~2 million rows.

[background: I'm working on a multi-label classification problem and would need to calculate F1, precision and recall and as the no. labels are variable I thought I could chuck all of them into a big list and do the comparison that way]

Comment: BTW, you can create the data frame in one statement (and you don't need all these conversions): `mydata <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3), label = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e'))`

Comment: @dayne: Thanks for pointing to the question already answered. Before creating this question I did go through the SO recommended questions but did not come across this one.

Comment: @VictorK. Thanks, always more to learn about R

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at `?split`:

```
split(mydata$label, mydata$id)
#$`1`
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
#
#$`2`
#[1] "b" "d"
#
#$`3`
#[1] "a" "c" "d" "e"
```

Comment: (+1) Beat my by a second.